# Extract the last specific value in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to extract the last specific value in hive table. So, this is how look like my table approximatively :

```
id , date, statuts
1 ; 2020 ; complete;validate
2 ; 2020 ; invalidate;complete;validate
3 ; 2020 ; validate;incomplete;invalidate
4 ; 2020 ; invalidate;complete;invalidate
5 ; 2020 ; invalidate;complete;validate
```

I need all the rows, which have the last value of "statuts" on "validate", So the result should be :

```
id , date, statuts
1 ; 2020 ; complete;validate
2 ; 2020 ; invalidate;complete;validate
5 ; 2020 ; invalidate;complete;validate
```

I tried this query but it doesn't work :

```
select * from table where statuts='validate' ;
```

Thank you by advance  for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select * from table where statuts like '%;validate' ;
```

This filters on records whose  `statuts` *ends* with `';validate'`.

If it is possible that `statuts` would just contain `'validate'` (with no other status before), then you could do string concatenation (which is less efficient though):

```
select * from table where ';' || statuts like '%;validate' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`:

```
select *
from table
where statuts like '%;validate'
```